# How to start another activity from a non activity class?

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener, baseadapter

I have an `onClickListener` in a class that extends `baseAdapter`, from which I want to start another activity, but **Eclipse** won't accept `startActivity(Intent)`. It gives the following error:

*The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}*

How can I fix this?

```
    public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  
    private Context mContext;
    public FeedListAdapter(Context cxt) {
        mContext = cxt;
    }
    public Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return feedItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        final TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
        TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
        NetworkImageView profilePic = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

        FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);

        name.setText(item.getName());

        // Converting timestamp into x ago format
        //CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                //Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
                //System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        timestamp.setText(item.getTimeStamp());

        // Chcek for empty status message
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
            statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Checking for null feed url
        if (item.getUrl() != null) {
            url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                    + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

            // Making url clickable
            url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // url is null, remove from the view
            url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // user profile pic
        profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

        // Feed image
        if (item.getImge() != null) {
            feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            feedImageView
                    .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        //onclick listner for listview items ;)

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Get the position
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, FinalShow.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("NAME", feedItems.get(+position).getName());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

This is my log:

```
10-06 20:43:39.976: D/AndroidRuntime(2247): Shutting down VM<br>
10-06 20:43:39.976: W/dalvikvm(2247): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (group=0x40a71930)<br>
10-06 20:43:40.006: E/AndroidRuntime(2247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main<br>
10-06 20:43:40.006: E/AndroidRuntime(2247): java.lang.NullPointerException<br>
10-06 20:43:40.006: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init> (ComponentName.java:75)<br>
10-06 20:43:40.006: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3491)<br>
10-06 20:43:40.006: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at   info.androidhive.listviewfeed.adapter.FeedListAdapter$2.onClick(FeedListAdapter.java:149)<br>
10-06 20:43:40.006: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) <br>
10-06 20:43:40.006: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at  android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)<br>
10-06 20:43:40.006: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at  android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)<br>
10-06 20:43:40.006: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)<br>
10-06 20:43:40.006: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)<br>
10-06 20:43:40.006: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)<br>
10-06 20:43:40.006: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)<br>
10-06 20:43:40.006: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)<br>
10-06 20:43:40.006: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)<br>
10-06 20:43:40.006: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)<br>
10-06 20:43:40.006: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `context.startActivity(intent)` , or in your code `activity.startActivity(intent)`

Comment: I tried this: convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //private Object activity; @Override public void onClick(View arg0) { // Get the position Intent intent = new Intent("info.androidhive.listviewfeed.adapter.FINALSHOW"); intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); intent.putExtra("NAME", feedItems.get(+position).getName()); context.startActivity(intent); } }); it gives an error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type Context"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this adapter for `listView` or `GridView`, you need to apply:

```
 setOnItemClickListener()
```

to the `listView` or `GridView` and on the

```
 onItemClicked()
```

method, you start the activity that you want.

i.e. write:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("info.androidhive.listviewfeed.adapter.FINALSHOW");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("NAME", feedItems.get(+position).getName());
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

this code on the `onItemClicked()` method.

Comment: its not working or perhaps i didn't do it correctly please elaborate.. i got this error " Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type Context"

Answer (score 0):

Try this before start the activity set this flag :

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Hope it will work.

Like this :

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Get the position
            Intent intent = new Intent("info.androidhive.listviewfeed.adapter.FINALSHOW");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("NAME", feedItems.get(+position).getName());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `startActivity` is an activity method, you can't use that in non Activity class. you need context of activity

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourNewActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass Context of activity in constructor of adapter class

```
private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();


    public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;

    }
```

&

```
this.activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It should be `this.activity.startActivity(intent)`.

Comment: @StephaneMathis not need for `this.activity`, when you use that in `onClick`, `activity` and `this.activity` is a same each other, `this` used for some place that you have same name in method and you want access class property

Comment: Yes.I got it. Thanku :)

Comment: how can i Pass Context of activity in constructor of adapter class??

Answer (score 0):

first, if you want to start an Activity, you should use Context or its child classes. 
Normally, we can pass the Context by constructor. For instance, your class:

```
public class YOURClass implements OnClickListener {
    private Context mContext;
    public YOURClass(Context cxt) {
        mContext = cxt;
        ...
    }
    ...
    @Override
    OnClick(View v) {
    ...
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    ...
    }
}
```

In Other Activity/Service...

```
...
YOURClass your = new YOURClass(cxt);
...
```

Comment: I tried this, it wont do a thing, please elaborate

public void onClick(View arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Intent intent = new Intent("info.androidhive.listviewfeed.adapter.FINALSHOW");
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  //Intent intent = new Intent(context, FinalShow.class);
  //intent.putExtra("NAME", feedItems.get(+position).getName());
  mContext.startActivity(intent);
 }

Comment: it says you have a null pointer exception in line 149. try to find out which variable in your class is null based on the log info.

Answer (score 0):

I had this:
`listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);` in my main activity, and this in my non activity class constructor

```
public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
        this.activity = activity;

        this.feedItems = feedItems;
    }
```

so this worked for me:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, FinalShow.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                activity.startActivity(intent);



            }
        });
```

**thanks everyone :)**

Answer (score 0):

Create another interface/callbacks which notifies the activity that the view has been clicked

eg.

```
public static interface MyCallback
{
    void onCustomElementClicked(View v);
}
```

And set the interface to your adapter from the activity

```
MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         //Setup views and etc...
         FeedListAdapter adapter = new FeedListAdapter(...);
         adapter.setCustomCallback(new MyCallback()
         {
              void onCustomElementClicked(View arg0)
              {
                 // Get the position
                 Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, FinalShow.class);
                 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                 intent.putExtra("NAME", feedItems.get(+position).getName());
                 startActivity(intent);
              }
         });
         //... The rest of your code
    }
}
```

And in your adapter

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            myCallback.onCustomElementClicked(arg0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this from your FeedListAdapter class

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, FinalShow.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            activity.startActivity(intent);



        }
    });
```

and ADD this in your main activity class

```
        Your_ListView_object.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, FinalShow.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

hope your will understand from this....

Answer (score 0):

You can send context to the class,

```
 public XXX XXX(Context context , ...){
this.context = context ; 
.
.
```

The start activity like this

```
    context.startActivity(intent);
```